# function f(x) = x && x is unary or binary?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am currently studying Boolean algebra, here is what I learned from school ( If I understand correctly):

- A Boolean function of one variable (input): unary boolean function.
- A Boolean function of two variables (input): binary boolean function.
- A Boolean function of n variables (input): n-ary boolean function.

and

- ! is a unary Boolean function
- &&, ∥ are binary Boolean functions

So my question is if I have a function f(x) = x && x, is this unary or binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one variable $x$ so it is unary.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @SamathaP If you're happy with the answer (and I don't see any margin to improve it), then perhaps you may consider to accept it. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and other articles liked to from the [Help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) (the link is at the bottom right of this page).